# Passing string as a parameter in method overloading

Tags: java, overloading

```
package chapter3;
class MatchClass
{
    int x=0,y=0,z=0,res=0;
    float a=0,b=0,c=0,ress=0;
    String str=null;`enter code here`
    void add(int x,int y,int z)
    {
        res=x+y+z;
        System.out.println("Addition of integers="+res);
    }

    void add(float a, float b, float c)
    {
        ress=a+b+c;
        System.out.println("Addition of float values="+ress);
    }

    void add(String...str)
    {

        System.out.println("Concatenation of string="+str); 
    }
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        MatchClass ob=new MatchClass();
        ob.add(10,20,30);
        ob.add(3.5F,4.5F,6.0F);
        ob.add("Mountain","sick");

    }
}
```

---

here is the code that I have written and the output I am getting for string parameter that I have passed is quite ambiguous. Can someone please help me with a quick fix. 
P.S- I want to use varagrs concept for passing string values.

Comment: What programming language is this? Could be Java, but the backquoted string after `str=null;` makes me wonder.

Comment: yep, avoid it. My bad. Don't know how the heck that line came in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you're talking about is the output you get for the string function.
Something like :

```
Concatenation of string=[Ljava.lang.String;@6d06d69c
```

At the line

```
System.out.println("Concatenation of string="+ str);
```

You're printing the variable "str" but "str" is not a string, it is an array and an array is an object. So, in order to be printed the function .toString() is called implicitly on "str". The problem here is the method Object.toString() does not print the content of the array but the object's type and reference inside the memory.

To print the content of the array the following will work (at least JDK8 required)

```
System.out.println("Concatenation of string="+ String.join(",",str));
```

Comment: okay, could you please tell why do we have a comma in place of char sequence. i.e in String.join(",",str); And is there a way to print the strings without being separated by a comma, i.e concatenated form.

Comment: The first argument of String.join is the string that will serve as glu between the array's items. For the array str = {"a","b","c"} then String.join("xxx", src) = "axxxbxxxc" so if you only want to concatenate the items without any separator you will use String.join("", src) = "abc"

Comment: @naman_rai Hello, don't forget to mark the correct answer....Oups.... i was the only one to answer (sorry i'm greedy)